# Como registrar dependências com o Windsor que estão em camadas diferentes da aplicação?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, injeção-de-dependência, ioc

Como registrar dependências com o Windsor que estão em camadas diferentes da aplicação?

Eu não quero ficar referenciando todas as camadas da aplicação na camada de apresentação como a maioria faz por ai.

Tenho o seguinte erro que eu sei porque acontece, gostaria de saber se alguém poderia auxiliar para Registrar essas dependências que estão em outras camadas da aplicação sem ter que ficar referenciando tudo na camada de apresentação.

> Can't create component 'BlogNetApp.Implementation.ServiceAppUsuario'
>   as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
>
> 'BlogNetApp.Implementation.ServiceAppUsuario' is waiting for the
>   following dependencies:
>   - Service 'BlogNetDomain.Interfaces.Services.IUsuarioService' which was not registered.

Estou usando C# NET MVC container Windsor.

```
namespace BlogNet.Windsor
{
    public class PresentationInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(
                Component.For<IServiceAppUsuario>().ImplementedBy<ServiceAppUsuario>(),
                Component.For<IServiceAppRole>().ImplementedBy<ServiceAppRole>(),
                Component.For<IServiceAppQuote>().ImplementedBy<ServiceAppQuote>()
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Como disse antes, está dando erro porque não está sendo registrado as dependências que estão em outra camada. Não quero referenciar as outras camadas na camada de apresentação.

Comment: Olá @allansud! Qual linguagem de programação você esta usando? Se possível adicione mais informações a sua pergunta como linhas de seu código que esta dando problema e tudo que achar útil que possa ajudar. Você pode fazer isto clicando em [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/65471/edit)

Comment: @MateusDemboski estou usando .NET MVC com C#. Estou procurando alguém para me auxiliar a registrar dependências da injeção de dependência sem ficar referenciando todas as camadas do projeto na camada de apresentação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *composition root* - o sitio onde se registam as dependências - nao faz parte de nenhuma das camadas da aplicação. Daí o nome, *raiz*.

Logo, a composition root tem (e deve) referenciar todos os componentes da aplicação, independentemente das suas camadas.

Comment: Valeu pela dica, isso pelo menos norteou estudos...Achei algo que abriu mais a mente. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352363/composition-root-in-asp-net-mvc-ddd-application) _Dá uma olhada depois..._